# Why when I try to display the text inside a textarea on html it display eveything in one line?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
 <body> 
 <form>    
     <textarea id="textfield"></textarea> 
     <input type="button" onclick="func1()" value="Post"> 
   </form>  
   <p id="para"></p>
</body>
```

When I type in textarea all the special tags `<a>,<br>` etc are ignored when I display them inside a `<p>` also all what I typed is displayed on one line and it doesn't even matter that I pressed return or use `<br>`, textarea seems to be taking html tags and turn them into a simple text.

This is the function I use to display the text area in html:

```
function func1()
{            
      document.getElementById("para").innerHTML=document.getElementById("textfield").innerHTML;
}
```

How do I take text from textarea and display it on screen normally(not in one line).
How do I modify textarea for a user who doesn't know how to use tags? when pressing a simple return should be translated to `<br`

Comment: You need to use <html> tags that do what they actually do?

Comment: Take a look at these: http://www.bbcode.org/examples/

Comment: You don't understand my question, textarea is ignoring my html tags it displays the html tags as if it was a simple text

Comment: HTML tags are not rendered in a text area. Use `\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, for textareas you should use `value` and not `innerHTML`. Like this...

```
document.getElementById("para").innerHTML=document.getElementById("textfield").value;
```

Now, for the single line issue. In textarea, new lines are separated by \n. In your divs \n do not work. So you'll have to replace them with `<br>` tags. So rewriting your code snippet...

```
document.getElementById("para").innerHTML=document.getElementById("textfield").value.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br />");
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer, is it possible also to do the opposite? from paragraph to textarea to remove `<br>` and replace with "\n"

Answer (score 1):

The text in the textarea isn't html. It is just text, containing regular line break `"\n"`. To display them, you either need to enclose the text in a `pre` tag, or replace the `"\n"` with `<br>`.

I would do the latter, since `pre` doesn't break at all if there's no break in the text, so you'll have a single long line and a scrollbar.

Comment: What if I want to add a bold text? or what if I want to use a simple return key to break a line, for example look at stack overflow comment text area when I reach the end of the line it inserts automatically "\n" without me doing anything. is there a way to do it

Comment: If you want to add more markup, you may want to investigate a rich text editor or WYSIWYG editor. Textarea is for plain text, and the user would have to insert markup himself. If it's just about line breaks, then you could do a simple replace.

Answer (score 0):

`<textarea>` does not take HTML and interprets it. I think what you are looking for is a [Rich Text Editors](http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors) if you want your users to be able to modify text without knowing the `tag names`